# visual studio 2010 could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I know there is plenty of question on that subject, but I didn't find any useful answer about my problem.

I got a project from a co-worker using mercurial. Now when i open the project I cannot open any C# file and I get the following message:

> Could not load file or assembly, 'Microsoft.MSXML, Version =8.0.0.0,Culture = Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03ff5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The file specified is unfindable.

Any idea? I don't know exactly what is in the code, in fact I've never see or programmed the code until now, but I know the code is working and my co-worker manage to make a installer and the software is working fine.

Comment: You have a broken reference. Remove the broken reference from the project, and re-add the assembly.

Comment: looks like you'll need to install something to resolve the dependency. take a look here -> http://forums.asp.net/t/1342836.aspx?Cannot+load+file+or+assembly+Microsoft+MSXML+version+8+0+0+0

Comment: See [The use of MSXML is not supported in .NET applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815112). Why are you using MSXML? The .NET Framework gives you everything you need to work with XML.

Comment: What is the .Net Framework version of your application? If referenced DLL file is compiled in higher version of .Net Framework than your application Framework then you can't include it

Comment: I don't even know what MSXML is... I am Electric Engineer, I need to implement my USB programm into his programm. So what I need to do to compile and test?

Comment: You should talk to your coworker.

Comment: MSXML is Microsoft’s COM-based (i.e. non-.NET)  XML parser. .NET has its own .NET parsers in the namespace `System.Xml`. Maybe you should ask your co-worker to switch to `System.Xml` and remove the MSXML dependency.

Comment: What .NET framework do I need? Does it come with visual studio?

Comment: @Olivier Jacot- Descombes Also, the same error pop up when I try to create a Visual Studio project.

Comment: System.Xml is there from the beginning. Any Version will do. It is not part of Visual Studio, but part of the .Net Framework which is installed on your Windows system. If the error pups up when creating an empty project, then probably something must be wrong with your Windows installation. Does it help to install Microsoft Core XML Services as @Anton says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem inside Visual Studio 2010.

My resolution was:

1. I tried to create a basic C# applicaiton but the same error message pop-up
2. I tried to re-open a old project that I used to work on but the same error message pop-up.

So I used the following [utility](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2014/08/20/visual-studio-2010-uninstall-utility-back-online.aspx). I made a fresh install and how everything is working. I don't think it is the most efficient solution , but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install [Microsoft Core XML Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6276) to solve this problem

Comment: There is 3 potential files that could download. Is there any difference?

Comment: It depends on Windows version that you use. 64 bit? 32 bit? Use the right one.

Comment: I install the programm you mention, but I still get the problem

Comment: I didn't guessed. The problem is that your co-worker has something installed on his computer that registered required assembly in GAC. Are there any requirements to do something(install) before using this project? Googling show results about Document Explorer. Is it required?

Comment: Also as workaround you can ask you co-worker to get this assembly from his computer and share with you. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnwpowell/archive/2009/01/14/how-to-copy-an-assembly-from-the-gac.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete all folders in this path then rebuild your project.

C:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root